# Read Connection String From .INI File

Tags: vb6

I have a .ini file setup from which I read connection strings. I have a modeule to read the strings:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any _
    , ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Long _
    , ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long


Public Const iniPath = "\DBSettings.INI"


Public Sub Main()
Dim dbPath As String
Dim dbPath As String
dbPath = GetSetting("DataBase", "DBPath")
dbPath= GetSetting("DataBase", "DBPath")
Form1.Show

 End Sub


Private Function GetSetting(ByVal pHeading As String, ByVal pKey As String) As String
Const cparmLen = 100
Dim sReturn As String * cparmLen
Dim sDefault As String * cparmLen
Dim aLength As Long
aLength = GetPrivateProfileString(pHeading, pKey _
            , sDefault, sReturn, cparmLen, App.Path & iniPath)
GetSetting = Mid(sReturn, 1, aLength)
End Function
```

Now, I am trying to display the strings on click of a button:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Command1_Click()

MsgBox (dbPath)
MsgBox (dbPath)

End Sub
```

However, it seems the form cannot see the variables in the module. How may I fix this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbPath` is declared in a `sub` so scoping rules state that the variable only exists within that sub.

To make a variable visible everywhere declare it in a module with the `public` access modifier:

`public dbPath as string`

And remove the `dim` in `main()`

Comment: Thanks that worked. In addition, how can I access the connection string values from the module if they are declared in the module's main as above?

Answer (score 1):

DBPath is a **Procedure Scope** variable, as it is declared inside a Procedure (Sub Main()).
It will not be visible from other modules, or even the module itself.
And also, you cannot declare a Public variable inside a Procedure (Sub or Function).

For further info regarding variable scope:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx